# About changing the passed variable to the function

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function which converts a one-indexed 2d array to a 1d array.
Example:

Given array:

```
array(0 => array("name"=>"Roberts", "email"=>"email@email.com"));
```

Returned array:

```
array("name"=>"Roberts", "email"=>"email@email.com");
```

the function is like this:

```
function to_1d_array($array)
{
   return $array[0];
}
```

But I want the function to change the passed variable directly returning anything. Should I user `referencing` or what?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your final outcome would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use pass-by-reference, like this:

```
function to_1d_array(&$array)
{
   $array = $array[0];
}
```

Notice the ampersand (`&`) just before the `$array` parameter.

The [PHP documentation on this topic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) has more information if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, change to:

```
function to_1d_array(&$array)
{
   $array=$array[0];
}
```